# Game data on PS4 lost

Tags: ps4

I added a new user on my PS4 and I was trying to do fortnite split screen but it did not work. I turned of my PS4 then left. After a while I came back and the PS4 was reset. Some game data was lost including god of war and GTA5 but the trophies and achievements were still there. My PS+ membership just ended recently if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you’ve lost your save data and you do not have a PlayStation Plus subscription, that data is permanently gone.

However, if your membership expired **after** you lost your save data, you may be in luck. According to [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/9jfbiw/how_long_does_ps_plus_keep_your_cloud_saves_after/e6qxsp6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf), cloud saves remain in Sony’s servers for 6 months after the expiration of your membership, so if you rejoin PS+ at any time within these 6 months, you can access your lost data.